# How to attach a few entities to context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here is code:

```
public void CreateNewAttempt(QuizAttemptDto attemptModel)
{
    var attempt = Mapper.Map<QuizAttemptDto, QuizAttempt>(attemptModel);

    _context.Set<Student>().Attach(attempt.Student);
    _context.Set<Quiz>().Attach(attempt.Quiz);

    _context.Attempts.Add(attempt);

    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I attach 1 entity, it's working fine, but when I'm trying to attach 2 entities, I'm getting an error

> Attaching an entity failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value

Comment: Are you sure your not using the same PK when adding multiple entities as you did when you tested it with one entity? Is your DB assigning ID's or are you assigning them in code?

Comment: Your inserting an entity with the same id. Change your automapper config to ignore the id field when mapping a DTO to entity: `CreateMap<QuizAttemptDto, QuizAttempt>().ForMember(x => x.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());`

Comment: Thanks, man! It's brilliant! Working fine! Thank you for the fast answer.